# Farthest and closest point in the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 80$ to the point (1,2)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I used the Pythagorean theorem to represent the distance $\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2}$.

Then I used the Langragian to obtain the following equation:

$\mathcal{L}(x,y) = \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2} - \lambda(x^2 + y^2)$

After the evaluation of the partial derivatives and solving the equations I found:
$x = \frac{1}{2}y$, by substitution in the circle equation I found $\frac{5}{4}y^2 = 80$ which means $y = \pm 8$ and by using substitution again we find $x = \pm4$.
So we have 4 possibilities for finding the min and max: $(4,8) (-4,8) (4,-8) (-4,-8)$

I literally substituted each one and found that $(-4,-8)$ is max and $(4,8)$ is min.
My first question is: is this correct?

My second question is what happened to lambda? How exactly is lambda useful here (also in general?) I understand why it exists (because the two gradient vectors are collinear but not necessarily equal) but I don't understand how it can be used! I know this is a weird question but I am confused.

Comment: The point $(1,2)$ is inside the circle so construct a diameter through $(1,2)$. One end of that diameter will be the closest and the other will be the farthest.

Comment: Not really answering your question, but: couldn't you simply express the circle $x^2+y^2=80$ parametrically, then express the distance to point (1,2) as a function of that parameter, and just find the maximum w.r.t. the parameter?  That is a straightforward single-value calculus problem.

Comment: Two of those four points don't satisfy your equation $x = \frac{1}{2} y$.

Answer (score 2):

You are over-complicating this. Your answers are correct but you don't need Lagrange multipliers.

If a point $p$ is inside a circle $C$ then the shortest and farthest distances to $C$ lie along a diameter through $p$.

To see why this is true, we look at two cases.

If $p$ is the center of the circle, then every point on $C$ is equidistant from $p$ so it doesn't matter.

If $p$ is not the center of the circle then there will be two distances along a diameter through $p$: $r_m$ and $r_M$ where $r_m\lt r_M$.

Construct two circles $C_m$ and $C_M$ of radii $r_m$ and $r_M$, respectively, centered at $p$. Both of these circles will be tangent to $C$.

The circle of radius $r_m$ will be inside of $C$. Since the point a distance of $r_m$ from $p$ is the only point on $C$ and every other point on $C_m$ lies inside of $C$, every other point that is a distance of $r_m$ away is closer to all other points of $C$. Therefore, that point is the closest.

The circle $C_M$ of radius $r_M$ will contain the circle $C$. Therefore, the point on $C$ that is a distance of $r_M$ from $p$ will be the only point on $C$ and since $C$ is contained in $C_M$, every other point on $C$ will be closer. Therefore, the point on $C_M$ a distance of $r_M$ away from $p$ will be the farthest.

For your special case, the diameter through $(1,2)$ is the line $y=2x$. This gives $$x^2+(2x)^2=80\implies 5x^2=80\implies x^2=16\implies x=\pm 4$$

This gives the two points $(4,8)$ and $(-4,-8)$ as you found using Lagrange multipliers.